# How to connect a 4:1 balun to a a log periodic antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna, ham-radio, antenna-array

I'm following a plan for a home made LTE/4G UHF antenna here: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3221812
...because it looks to be of a very similar to design to a very expensive 4G anntenna I know works very well.

However it's not completely clear how to wire it up. It looks like it has two element arrays on opposite sides, and that they appear to be wired from the pointed end (with shorter elements) rather than the opposite end.  I assume the LTE mast should be at the pointed end of the array? And that it should be vertically polarised like a normal dipole?

If I also add the 4:1 balun (I've no idea what this actually does!) I'm not sure how this is actually wired to the antenna elements and coaxial cable and what is classed as "earth" in this setup?  Does earth just mean the outer shield of the coax cable?

Comment: I get a warning from my virus checker on connecting to that site. No charge for this advice!

Comment: Really? which AV software are you running? That's a VERY well known site in the 3D printing community.  If you google "3d printing models" it will almost certainly be #1.

Comment: McAfee but, just went back and it doesn't detect anything now. How odd.

Comment: Viruses aside, do you have any clue about my question :)

Comment: Not really, I didn't want to spend much time looking at the linked site in case there was something lurking there to bite me. 1st and only impressions was that it wasn't technical enough for me to get my teeth into.